# RecyclerView with different Cardlayouts

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

**What I'd like to do**

---

At the moment I'm playing around with `RecyclerView` and `CardView`'s. For now I wrote a `RecyclerView.Adapter` on which I can display the same CardView multiple times with different content - analog to the `ListView` with a `BaseAdapter`.

Now I'd like to write a `RecyclerView` with different `CardView-Layout`'s (in style of Google Now). I've already searched for tutorials but didn't found anything useful about that topic. Does someone know, how this needs to be implemented? What needs to be done to realize that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html. And for diferent layouts just change the ViewType on your adapter

Comment: @PedroOliveira I already read that, but it only show's how it'sdone with one card, and not different ones.

Comment: You have to override `getItemViewType` on your adapter and return a diferent viewtype so you can inflate diferent layouts on your `onCreateViewHolder` (which receives the viewtype as 2º parameter)

Comment: @PedroOliveira do you have a short example for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25960103/3410697 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/3410697

Comment: Check  another solution in these link which can also useful for you  http://stackoverflow.com/a/39972276/3946958

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To achieve what you want you need to override [`getItemViewType(position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) on your `RecyclerView.Adapter`, Where you'll return an `int` telling you what kind of view will be used to represent this position.

Next you will create different `ViewHolders` on [`createViewHolder (parent,viewType)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#createViewHolder%28android.view.ViewGroup,%20int%29) which will keep the references to each distinct CardLayout in your case.

Then on [`bindViewHolder(holder, position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#bindViewHolder%28VH,%20int%29) you can create a switch statement or if else cases to go through your list of possible views and fill them with data.

Sample code below:

```
public GeneralViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

    GeneralViewHolder holder;
    View v;
    Context context = viewGroup.getContext();

    if (viewType == FIRST_TYPE) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.first_card, viewGroup, false);

        holder = new FirstTypeViewHolder(v); //Of type GeneralViewHolder
    } else {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.second_card, viewGroup, false);
        holder = new SecondTypeViewHolder(v);
    }

    return holder;
}

public void onBindViewHolder(GeneralViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    if(getItemViewType(i)==FIRST_TYPE) {
        FirstTypeViewHolder holder1 = (FirstTypeViewHolder)viewHolder;
    } else {
        SecondTypeViewHolder holder1 = (SecondTypeViewHolder)viewHolder;
    }
}

public int getItemViewType (int position) {
    //Some logic to know which type will come next;
    return Math.random()<0.5 ? FIRST_TYPE : SECOND_TYPE;
}
```

Comment: how to implement on click to different layout ??