# Android - How to have different set of CardView in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm able to use RecyclerView with a CardView to display a set of info.

But how do I display 2 different sets of cardview in a RecyclerView. For example, in the image below, Updates contain list of cardview items that needs update while Recently Update contains list of cardview items that has been updated recently.
[image]

Comment: Consider this answer. It helped me. Cheers!
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28110377/900105