# RecyclerView With Multiple Layouts

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView to display text in CardView but I want to add a Header TextView at the top of the RecyclerView that looks like this:

[image]

So I made another layout file "top_header.xml" with just a TextView but I am not sure how to modify the adapter to get both layouts in there.

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

List<AdapterData> mItems;

public Adapter() {
    super();
    mItems = new ArrayList<AdapterData>();
    AdapterData data = new AdapterData();
    data.setCode("dummytext");
    data.setResult("dummytext");
    mItems.add(data);

    data = new AdapterData();
    data.setCode("dummytext");
    data.setResult("dummytext");
    mItems.add(data);

    data = new AdapterData();
    data.setCode("dummytext");
    data.setResult("dummytext");
    mItems.add(data);

    data = new AdapterData();
    data.setCode("dummytext");
    data.setResult("dummytext");
    mItems.add(data);

    data = new AdapterData();
    data.setCode("dummytext");
    data.setResult("dummytext");
    mItems.add(data);

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int viewType = 0;
    return viewType;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == 0) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.top_textview, parent, false));
    }

    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_card_item, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    AdapterData data = mItems.get(position);
    viewHolder.code.setText(data.getCode());
    viewHolder.result.setText(data.getResult());

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}


class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView header;

    public ViewHolder1(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        header = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.header_textview);

    }
}

class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView code;
    public TextView result;

    public ViewHolder2(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        code = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.sims_code);
        result = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.sims_result);

    }
}


}
```

Comment: ok I have gotten up to this point and I think its right but not sure what must with the current onBindViewHolder code should I create another BindHolder *code updated*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add multiple types of views (more than 2 types) and not just a `header` and "normal" `item`, [CommonsWare answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30844680/1993204) is perfect. But if the two mentioned types (`header` and `item`) are enough for you, the answer can be a lot simpler (from the practical point of view).

There are two relatively simple libraries that you can use for that:

1. [**`RecyclerViewHeader`**](https://github.com/blipinsk/RecyclerViewHeader) - super simple to use, but uses a bit "hacky" approach, that sometimes can cause problems. Suitable for relatively simple headers.
2. [**`HeaderRecyclerView`**](https://github.com/Karumi/HeaderRecyclerView) - Suitable for any type of header. Implements approach mentioned by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30844680/1993204) to inflate two types of views. A bit more difficult to use than `RecyclerViewHeader` but nothing too hard to use on a daily basis.

***For disclosure***: I am the author of the [**`RecyclerViewHeader`**](https://github.com/blipinsk/RecyclerViewHeader). I'm aware of its flaws, therefore I'm not trying to promote it as one-for-all solution, but more as an interesting alternative to complicating your adapter. [**`HeaderRecyclerView`**](https://github.com/Karumi/HeaderRecyclerView) is a nice piece of code that can simplify your work. I use it myself when my `RecyclerView` header gets complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make three changes:

1. Implement `getItemViewType()` on your `RecyclerView.Adapter`, to return a unique integer for each view type needed by your app, based on the supplied `position`. So, you would return one value for your header (presumably a `position` of `0`) and another value for everything else.
2. Pay attention to the `viewType` parameter passed into `onCreateViewHolder()`, and create an appropriate `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` as needed. This in turn probably means that you should have different `ViewHolder` classes for your header and detail rows.
3. In `onBindViewHolder()`, apply binding logic based upon the type of the `ViewHolder` that you get, so you bind the appropriate data into the `ViewHolder`. You can use `instanceof`, or have the `ViewHolder` classes implement a common interface, or whatever to make this work.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/HeaderList) demonstrates a `RecyclerView` with section headers that implements the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

Have to create different type of **View holder** and also have **bind the data** according to view holder views. This Question is already asked and answer [Recyclerview and handling different type of row inflation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914003/recyclerview-and-handling-different-type-of-row-inflation/29255943#29255943) here and it will help you