# Multiple views in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, view, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I'm working with a `recyclerView` in my app that has three different layouts for it's rows.

I change the visibility of the different views in the layout for each row depending on the the type of data. For example, if it's a text post I change the visibility of the `imageView` to invisible and if it's an image post I change the visibility of the `textView`.

Is this a bad practice? Will this be too much overhead for the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844460/recyclerview-with-multiple-layouts) answer.

Main idea - you should implement getItemViewType of appropriate adapter and create layout accordingly with type returned by getItemViewType

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance!

Answer (score 1):

It's not the best approach. See this: [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

There are also libraries in case you need more complex behavior while keeping a clean structure. For example, see [Groupie](https://github.com/lisawray/groupie).