# Scalable Recycle view

Tags: android, listview, view, android-recyclerview

I am working on an application, in that we are trying to create user feed and final goal is to create feeds like facebook. Every card in feed has some different behaviour or different set of properties or click behaviour.

Right now, there is a recycler view with multiple card holder and there is a switch state to populate data in different cards. But it is difficult to maintain lots of callback like one to open play video, one for open menu, open web article and many more.

I just want to know the best practise for this. And code or tips any thing will work.

Thanks

Comment: You should probably see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914003/recyclerview-and-handling-different-type-of-row-inflation). Cheers

Comment: i m doing this.
Is this the best practise with recyclerview?