# Recyclerview Inflate 2 Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I develop voucher page that load all available voucher. But I need to also include slideshow in it.

Recyclerview include 2 main layout:

- Slideshow (`slideshow.xml`)
- Card View (`card_view_horizontal.xml`)

My current code used to load cardview only to recyclerview.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by venkataprasad on 02-01-2015.
 */
public class VoucherDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VoucherDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static ArrayList<FeddProperties> dataSet;

    public VoucherDataAdapter(ArrayList<FeddProperties> os_versions) {

        dataSet = os_versions;
    }


    @Override
    public VoucherDataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
// create a new view
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.card_view_horizontal, null);

        // create ViewHolder

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VoucherDataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        FeddProperties fp = dataSet.get(i);

        viewHolder.tvVersionName.setText(fp.getTitle());
        viewHolder.iconView.setImageResource(fp.getThumbnail());
        viewHolder.feed = fp;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }

    // inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView tvVersionName;
        public ImageView iconView;

        public FeddProperties feed;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);

            tvVersionName = (TextView) itemLayoutView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvVersionName);
            iconView = (ImageView) itemLayoutView
                    .findViewById(R.id.iconId);

            itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), VoucherDetailActivity.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "os version is: " + feed.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


        }

    }
}
```

If you have any suggestions, let me know.

Comment: please post xml code.

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer on stack [RecyclerView with multiple view type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

you need to implement `getItemViewType(),`

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Just as an example, return 0 or 2 depending on position
        // Note that unlike in ListView adapters, types don't have to be contiguous
        return position % 2 * 2;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         switch (viewType) {
             case 0: return new ViewHolder0(...);
             case 2: return new ViewHolder2(...);
             ...
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what your question states, you need a recyclerview that inflates your `slideshow.xml` (probably in position `0`) and `card_view_horizontal.xml` in rest of the list.

check [this article](http://code2concept.blogspot.com/2015/10/android-multiple-row-layout-using.html) .

I'm sure that is what you want.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914003/recyclerview-and-handling-different-type-of-row-inflation)