# How to inflate Hashmap<String,List<Items>> into the Recyclerview

Tags: android, list, hashmap, android-recyclerview

I want that the string of keys must act as header and the list must be inflated under that map key in the `RecyclerView`.

thanks for any help

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

private WeakHashMap<String, List<VideoItem>> mData = new WeakHashMap<>();
private ArrayList<String> mKeys;
ArrayList<WeakHashMap<String,List<VideoItem>>> hashMapArrayList;

public Adapter(WeakHashMap<String, List<VideoItem>> mData, ArrayList<WeakHashMap<String,List<VideoItem>>> hashMapArrayList) {
    this.mData = mData;
    this.hashMapArrayList=hashMapArrayList;
    mKeys = new ArrayList<String>(mData.keySet());
}

public String getKey(int position)
{
    return (String) mKeys.get(position);
}


@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.player_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String key = getKey(position);
    WeakHashMap<String, List<VideoItem>> value = hashMapArrayList.get(position);
    MyViewHolder holder1=(MyViewHolder)holder;
    holder1.header.setText(key);
    holder1.value.setText(value.get( key ).get( position ).getDuration());
    Log.v( "KEY",key );
    Log.v( "VALUE", String.valueOf( value ) );
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != hashMapArrayList ? hashMapArrayList.size() : 0);

}

//    public  ArrayList<WeakHashMap<String,List<VideoItem>>> getItem(int position) {
//        return hashMapArrayList.get(mKeys.get(position));
//    }

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView header ;
    TextView value;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        header= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.header);
        value= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_name);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: post your adapter code, we will help from there

Comment: try to use this: https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview

Comment: i want to make sections in the recyclerview using key as sections and list value under those sections

Comment: i can't use others library.

Comment: You cannot do what you want.A recycler view implementation(unless you use or make a complex library) cannot display nested set of objects (in your case a header and the child items). You need to move all the items into a single arraylist specifying differnt item types and then display them using the different view types functionality of a recycler view.

Comment: As for sticky headers,you will see from @RohitArya's comment.The library he mentions uses a completely different approach .if you want a normal header(it will not _stick_ to the top of the screen).You can go ahead with what i mentioned in the previous comment

Comment: you can use multiple views (in your case 2) for `RecyclerView`. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914003/recyclerview-and-handling-different-type-of-row-inflation

Comment: thanks @RohitArya i'll try it

Comment: @ShikhaRatra; is it resolved without a third-party lib?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve it easily with the library [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter). You can group your items into sections and add a header to each section:

```
class MySection extends StatelessSection {

    String title;
    List<VideoItem> list;

    public MySection(String title, List<VideoItem> list) {
        // call constructor with layout resources for this Section header and items 
        super(R.layout.section_header, R.layout.section_item);

        this.title = title;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return list.size(); // number of items of this section
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        // return a custom instance of ViewHolder for the items of this section
        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your view here
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        return new SimpleHeaderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        MyHeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (MyHeaderViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your header view here
        headerHolder.tvItem.setText(title);
    }
}
```

Then you set up the RecyclerView with your Sections:

```
// Create an instance of SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

// Create your sections with the list of data from your HashMap
for(Map.Entry<String, List<VideoItem>> entry : mData.entrySet()) {
    MySection section = new MySection(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    // add your section to the adapter
    sectionAdapter.addSection(section);

}

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```

If you can't use 3rd party libs you can have a look on how it is implemented [here](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter/blob/master/library/src/main/java/io/github/luizgrp/sectionedrecyclerviewadapter/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.java).

Comment: @ymerdrengene yes it worked, have a look in the lib....you need to customize it according to your need....

Comment: @ShikhaRatra Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Map<String, List<String>> maplist = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
arraylist.add("Sample text"); // Add more strings...
maplist.put("key",arraylist); // Add more lists...
```

Comment: i have proper data as Map<String, List<String>>. i don't know how to inflate that data properly in the recyclerview as key as header and list under that key