# How to group the datas in listview of same date

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am creating an android application in which i fetch the datas from sqlite database and display it in listview this part works fine but i want to group the data in listview which has same date.Can anyone tell me how to group the listitems based on same date in listview.

CustomAdapter:

```
public class NewDaybookAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<Daybooklist> daybooklists;
DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;
boolean isListScrolling;

public NewDaybookAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Daybooklist> daybooklists) {
    this.context = context;
    this.daybooklists = daybooklists;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return daybooklists.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return daybooklists.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertview == null)
        convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_daybook_newitem, null);
    final TextView day_name = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_name);
    final TextView day_description = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_description);
    final TextView day_type = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_type);
    final TextView day_amount = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_amount);
    final TextView day_usertype = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_usertype);
    final TextView day_time = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_time);
    final ImageView day_check = (ImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.img_doneall);
    final TextView daybook_location = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_location);
    final TextView daybook_date = (TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
    final LinearLayout linear_date = (LinearLayout)convertview.findViewById(R.id.li_date);

    databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    final Daybooklist m = daybooklists.get(position);
    if (m.getUsertype() != null && !m.getUsertype().isEmpty()) {
        String s = m.getSdate();
        String[] spiliter = s.split("-");
        String year = spiliter[0];
        String month = spiliter[1];
        String date = spiliter[2];
        if (month.startsWith("01")) {
            daybook_date.setText(date + "Jan" + year);
        } else if (month.startsWith("02")) {
            daybook_date.setText(date + "Feb" + year);
        } else if (month.startsWith("03")) {
            daybook_date.setText(date + "Mar" + year);
        } else if (month.startsWith("04")) {
            daybook_date.setText(date + "Apr" + year);
        } else if (month.startsWith("05")) {
            daybook_date.setText(date + "May" + year);
        } else if (month.startsWith("06")) {
            daybook_date.setText(date + "Jun" + year);
        } else if (month.startsWith("07")) {
            daybook_date.setText(date + "Jul" + year);
        } else if (month.startsWith("08")) {
            daybook_date.setText(date + "Aug" + year);
        } else if (month.startsWith("09")) {
            daybook_date.setText(date + "Sep" + year);
        } else if (month.startsWith("10")) {
            daybook_date.setText(date + "Oct" + year);
        } else if (month.startsWith("11")) {
            daybook_date.setText(date + "Nov" + year);
        } else if (month.startsWith("12")) {
            daybook_date.setText(date + "Dec" + year);
        }


        if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("farmer") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("singleworker") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("groupworker") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("payvehicle")) {
            if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("farmer")) {
                day_name.setText(m.getName());
                day_description.setText(m.getDescription());
                String locat = String.valueOf(databaseHandler.getfarmerlocation(m.getMobileno()));
                locat = locat.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
                Log.e("farmerlocation", locat);
                daybook_location.setText(locat);
                day_type.setText(m.getType());
                if (m.getName() != null && m.getName().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_name.setText(" ");
                } else if (m.getDescription() != null && m.getDescription().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_description.setText(" ");
                }

                day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + m.getExtraamt());
                if (m.getAmountout().startsWith("0.0") | m.getAmountout().startsWith("0")) {
                    //     day_amount.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                    Log.e("Amountout", m.getAmountout());
                    day_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    //    day_amount.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.album_title));
                    Log.e("Amountout", m.getAmountout());
                    day_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                day_time.setText(m.getCtime());
            } else {
                day_name.setText(m.getName());
                day_description.setText(m.getDescription());
                daybook_location.setText(m.getType());
                day_type.setText(m.getType());
                if (m.getName() != null && m.getName().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_name.setText(" ");
                } else if (m.getDescription() != null && m.getDescription().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_description.setText(" ");
                }

                day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + m.getExtraamt());
                if (m.getAmountout().startsWith("0.0") | m.getAmountout().startsWith("0")) {
                    //  day_amount.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                    Log.e("Amountout", m.getAmountout());
                    day_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    //  day_amount.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.album_title));
                    Log.e("Amountout", m.getAmountout());
                    day_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                day_time.setText(m.getCtime());
            }


        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("advancefarmer") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("workeradvance") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("kgroupadvance") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("otherexpense") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("vehicle")) {
            if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("advancefarmer")) {
                day_name.setText(m.getName());
                day_description.setText(m.getDescription());
                day_type.setText(m.getType());
                String locat = String.valueOf(databaseHandler.getfarmerlocation(m.getMobileno()));
                locat = locat.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
                Log.e("farmerlocation", locat);
                daybook_location.setText(locat);
                if (m.getName() != null && m.getName().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_name.setText(" ");
                } else if (m.getDescription() != null && m.getDescription().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_description.setText(" ");
                }
                Log.e("amountout", m.getAmountout());
                day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + m.getAmountout());
                day_time.setText(m.getCtime());
            } else {
                day_name.setText(m.getName());
                day_description.setText(m.getType());
                day_type.setText(m.getType());
                daybook_location.setText(m.getDescription());
                if (m.getName() != null && m.getName().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_name.setText(" ");
                } else if (m.getDescription() != null && m.getDescription().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_description.setText(" ");
                }
                Log.e("amountout", m.getAmountout());
                day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + m.getAmountout());
                day_time.setText(m.getCtime());
            }


        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("buyer")) {
            day_name.setText(m.getName());
            day_description.setText(m.getDescription());
            day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + m.getAmountin());
            day_type.setText(" ");
            day_time.setText(m.getCtime());
            daybook_location.setText(m.getType());
        }

    }


    return convertview;
}
```

}

Database query:

```
public ArrayList<Daybooklist> getAlldaybookitemsentries() {
    ArrayList<Daybooklist> daybooklists = new ArrayList<Daybooklist>();
    String selectquery = "SELECT daybookusertype,amountin,amountout,otheramount,daybookname,daybookdescription,daybooktype,mobileno,date,daybooktime FROM daybookdetails  ORDER BY date DESC";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectquery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Daybooklist daybooklistentries = new Daybooklist();               
            daybooklistentries.setUsertype(cursor.getString(0));
            daybooklistentries.setAmountin(cursor.getString(1));
            daybooklistentries.setAmountout(cursor.getString(2));
            daybooklistentries.setExtraamt(cursor.getString(3));
            daybooklistentries.setName(cursor.getString(4));
            daybooklistentries.setDescription(cursor.getString(5));
            daybooklistentries.setType(cursor.getString(6));
            daybooklistentries.setMobileno(cursor.getString(7));
            daybooklistentries.setSdate(cursor.getString(8));
            daybooklistentries.setCtime(cursor.getString(9));
            daybooklists.add(daybooklistentries);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return daybooklists;
}
```

Output i am getting:
 [image]

Comment: what do you mean by group ? you want to show the same date once ?

Comment: Yes i want to show the same date once

Comment: I think there is no direct functionality on listview to group the items by a certain value. However, the idea is to use `concat` from your SQL query-> group it by date -> select the concatenated value and the date-> store the values -> from the adapter split the value -> and use Expandable List view to handle your sub items
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Answer (score 1):

Try it...

```
TextView messagedate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.datedetailstext);

if(position == 0) {
    messagedate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    messagedate.setText(messageslist.getDate());
} else {
    if(messageslist.get(position - 1).getDate().equals(messageslist.get(position).getDate())) {
        messagedate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        messagedate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        messagedate.setText(messageslist.getDate());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HashMap or ArrayMap with String date as key and in value put arraylist.
As this can be hard for newbie, but you can use this data with sectioned recyclerview.

For more about sectioned recyclerview check [this](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/4c189fb1124df4556058). and for Hashmap with recyclerview check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36351417/how-to-inflate-hashmapstring-listitems-into-the-recyclerview).

Answer (score 0):

Store previousDate and then compare with current one. if it matches don't set the date!

```
String previousDate=""; //make it global


        String fullDate="";
        if (month.startsWith("01")) {
            fullDate =date + "Jan" + year;
        } else if (month.startsWith("02")) {
            fullDate =date + "Feb" + year;
        } else if (month.startsWith("03")) {
            fullDate =date + "Mar" + year;
        } else if (month.startsWith("04")) {
            fullDate =date + "Apr" + year;
        } else if (month.startsWith("05")) {
            fullDate =date + "May" + year;
        } else if (month.startsWith("06")) {
            fullDate =date + "Jun" + year;
        } else if (month.startsWith("07")) {
            fullDate =date + "Jul" + year;
        } else if (month.startsWith("08")) {
            fullDate =date + "Aug" + year;
        } else if (month.startsWith("09")) {
            fullDate =date + "Sep" + year;
        } else if (month.startsWith("10")) {
            fullDate =date + "Oct" + year;
        } else if (month.startsWith("11")) {
            fullDate =date + "Nov" + year;
        } else if (month.startsWith("12")) {
            fullDate =date + "Dec" + year;
        }

        if (!fullDate.equals(previousDate)){
            previousDate =fullDate;
            daybook_date.setText(date + "Dec" + year);
        }
```

Comment: when the listview gets scrolled the date is not visible

Comment: isn't that supposed to be ?!! date for the first item only

Comment: For every item  i have to check it

Comment: what does that mean? this sets the date for the first entry of any day. if you want for every item how's that called group?  **did you put the previous date as global variable?**

Comment: Yes i have put the previous date as global variable

Comment: sorry, I am not getting what's your problem now. can you share in details?

Comment: When the list is opened at first it shows the date properly when i swipe down and swipe up the date is not visible

Comment: tough to check on my end. please check your listview adapter/events. use this algorithm to set date once.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. Order the data by date, usually a timestamp
2. If you don't need to folder the group, just add another item showing the date
3. If you want to folder/unfolder the group, you need to try add customized items groups