# how to display multiply layout in RecyclerView

Tags: android

I am getting data in jSON. Data contains images url. I am trying to display images in below layouts.

```
1Image
2Image
3Image  4Image  5Image  6Image  7image
8Image  9Image  10Image 11Image 12image
13image 14image 15image 16image 17image
....    ....     .....  ......   .....
```

So First two image will be in vertically. Other 5 images in horizontal scroll view and so on.
So i am using RecyclerView with vertical orientation. but i am not able to creating the logic so images will be display above format.

please anyone guide me.

update:-

```
//Horizontal images view.
public class MoviesAdapterHorizontal extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapterHorizontal.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<String> moviesList;
   // private ThumbnailListener thumbnailListener;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      //  YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail;
        ImageView imageView2;
        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
              //  thumbnail = (YouTubeThumbnailView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            imageView2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        }
    }


    public MoviesAdapterHorizontal(List<String> moviesList) {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
    //    thumbnailListener = new ThumbnailListener();
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.hotrow2, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final String url = moviesList.get(position);
        System.out.println("movie url = " + url);

       final String m = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        System.out.println("url = "+m);

      int w = BasicDeviceInfo.getWidth(getActivity());
        //  int h = BasicDeviceInfo.getHeight(getActivity());


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        w/3);

        AQuery aq = new AQuery(holder.imageView2);

        aq.id(holder.imageView2).image("http://x.x.x.231/news-flicks/uploads/home/tulips_e84aa48cee1a2a25aef001cd74152663.jpg", true, true, 0,
                R.drawable.no_thumbnail);

        holder.imageView2.setLayoutParams(lParams);

       // holder.thumbnail.setLayoutParams(lParams);

      /*  holder.thumbnail.setTag(m);
        holder.thumbnail.initialize("AIzaSyDW-sxPUqy2rD6ZWs3vTNb0jKEKA21RjrY", thumbnailListener);

        holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FullscreenDemoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("url",m);
               intent.putExtra("txt", "");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });*/

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesList.size();
    }

    private final class ThumbnailListener implements
            YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener,
            YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(
                YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader) {
            loader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(this);
            String videoId = (String) view.getTag();
            loader.setVideo(videoId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(
                YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeInitializationResult loader) {
            view.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_thumbnail);
        }

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView view, String videoId) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {
            view.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_thumbnail);
        }
    }

}
```

horizontal xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/no_thumbnail"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

i am calling it parent recycle view onBindViewHolder()

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Videos movie = moviesList.get(position);
        System.out.println("Image = " + movie.getImage());

        int w = BasicDeviceInfo.getWidth(getActivity());
        //  int h = BasicDeviceInfo.getHeight(getActivity());
        if(position < 2) {

            final List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
            lst.add(movie.getVideo_url());
            lst.add(movie.getVideo_url());
            lst.add(movie.getVideo_url());
            lst.add(movie.getVideo_url());
            lst.add(movie.getVideo_url());


            final MoviesAdapterHorizontal adapter = new MoviesAdapterHorizontal(lst);
            holder.recyclerView2.setAdapter(adapter);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Now my horizontal  onBindViewHolder is calling and able to see log messages. But ImageView is not displaying. i think it is hiding or overlapping

Answer (score 0):

See onto this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914003/recyclerview-and-handling-different-type-of-row-inflation) for how to make different layout item in `RecyclerView`

For first two element layout file containing `ImageView`

For rest  item view I will suggest take Horizontal `RecyclerView` as item

#### My Custom view for Horizontal `RecyclerView`

```
public class DocumentViewDynamic extends LinearLayout {
private static final String LOG_TAG = DocumentViewDynamic.class.getSimpleName();
private final String titleStr;
private OnDocumentItemClicked callBack;

public void updateImage(Bitmap bitmap, int postionOfView) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "updateImage: ");
    documentAdapter.setImageFromCamera(bitmap, postionOfView);
}


public interface OnDocumentItemClicked {
    void onDocumentItemClicked(View v, int position);
}


public void setItemClickedListener(OnDocumentItemClicked callBack) {
    this.callBack = callBack;
}

@Bind(R.id.title)
TextView title;
@Bind(R.id.img_add)
FloatingActionButton imgAdd;
private DocumentAdapter documentAdapter;
private final Context context;

@Bind(R.id.rv_document)
RecyclerView rvDocument;

@OnClick(R.id.img_add)
public void addDummyImage() {
    documentAdapter.addSingelDummyImage();
    rvDocument.scrollToPosition(documentAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
}


public DocumentViewDynamic(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.DocumentViewDynamic, 0, 0);
    try {
        titleStr = ta.getString(R.styleable.DocumentViewDynamic_titleDoc);
    } finally {
        ta.recycle();
    }

    init();
}

public ArrayList<DocumentModel> getAllImageData() {
    return documentAdapter.getImageData();
}

private void init() {

    setOrientation(VERTICAL);

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.compund_view_document, this);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(titleStr))
        title.setText(titleStr);
    initRecyclerView();

}

private void initRecyclerView() {

    rvDocument.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, HORIZONTAL, false));
    ArrayList<DocumentModel> documentModels = new ArrayList<>();
    documentAdapter = new DocumentAdapter(documentModels);
    rvDocument.setAdapter(documentAdapter);

}


public class DocumentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DocumentAdapter.DocViewHolder> {
    public ArrayList<DocumentModel> getImageData() {
        return documentModels;
    }

    private ArrayList<DocumentModel> documentModels = new ArrayList<>();

    public DocumentAdapter(ArrayList<DocumentModel> documentModels) {
        this.documentModels = documentModels;
        if (documentModels.size() == 0)
            documentModels.add(new DocumentModel());
    }


    @Override
    public DocViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_compund_document, parent, false);
        return new DocViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final DocViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (documentModels.get(position).getBitmap() == null) {
            holder.imgDocument.setImageResource(R.drawable.camera);
            holder.imgBtnDelete.setVisibility(GONE);
        } else {
            holder.imgDocument.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
            holder.imgDocument.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            holder.imgDocument.setImageBitmap(documentModels.get(position).getBitmap());
            holder.imgBtnDelete.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                callBack.onDocumentItemClicked(DocumentViewDynamic.this, holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });


        holder.imgBtnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.getAdapterPosition() == 0 && documentModels.size() == 1) {
                    documentModels.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setBitmap(null);
                } else {
                    documentModels.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return (documentModels != null && documentModels.size() > 0) ? documentModels.size() : 0;
    }

    public void setImageFromCamera(Bitmap imageFromCamera, int postionOfView) {
        documentModels.get(postionOfView).setBitmap(imageFromCamera);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public class DocViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        @Bind(R.id.img_document)
        ImageView imgDocument;
        @Bind(R.id.img_btn_delete)
        ImageView imgBtnDelete;

        public DocViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }


    public void addSingelDummyImage() {

        if (documentModels.get(documentModels.size() - 1).getBitmap() != null) {
            documentModels.add(new DocumentModel());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Snackbar.make(rvDocument, "Please Add image ", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

#### layout file for compound view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textColor="#3399ff"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_document"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_add" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/img_add"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/fab_plus_bg" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

## Inflate this compound view as item in Vertical `RecyclerView`

Comment: I created multiple view. One view is working good for displaying image. Here I am displaying one image in one row. But I am confuse how other view will work like as horizontal scroll. Because one row contain 5 images. kindly suggest to me.

Comment: For rest item view I will suggest take Horizontal RecyclerView as item

Comment: Horizontal RecyclerView will also  work for API 11?

Comment: yes its in support lib

Comment: Thanks May you please share such type demo? I really new in android.I will be thank full for your help.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: kindly see my update. My horizontal onBindViewHolder is calling but layout is not displaying