# creating only one button on RecyclerView Scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Following is the code from `RecyclerView` `onBindViewHolder` method.

Inside the recycler view I am creating a button Dynamically as shown below.

```
@Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
          .
          .
          .
        Button button1 = new Button(context);
        holder.phoneContainer.addView(button1);
}
```

When I Scroll the App in Device (when Running in real Device), The Button is created again.

It is supposed to attach 1 button in every `cardview` but when ever I scroll the button is created.

Any way to remove the existing `views` inside `holder.phoneContainer` or

creating only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only a single `View` inside the `phoneContainer` you can do:

```
holder.phoneContainer.removeAllViews();
holder.phoneContainer.addView(button1);
```

Comment: What if there is More than one button ?

Comment: You will have to keep a reference to the added `button1` inside your `ViewHolder` and use `holder.phoneContainer.removeView(button1)`. Although I must say, using an `Adapter` THIS WAY is pretty terrible.

Comment: I have 3 Buttons created Dynamically. Using `removeAllViews()` solved the problem.

Will it consume more memory removing all views everytime during scroll?

[RecyclerView.Adapter Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)

Comment: Manipulating your `Views` (which includes both `adding` and `removing` `Views` to and from hierarchy) will use quite a lot of resources if you do it in `onBindViewHolder `. You should try to omit dynamic addition of `Views` inside `onBindViewHolder` in general.

Comment: Then how to create and attach views based on custom API response? Other suggestions?

Comment: You can do that in a million different ways. Everything depends on your particular case. My best guess is, in your case you could do it elegantly with a proper `Adapter` that can inflate multiple types of `Views`. There are tons of topics here on SO about that. For example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914003/recyclerview-and-handling-different-type-of-row-inflation)

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the views inside your container and the add your button.

```
        holder.phoneContainer.removeAllViews();
        Button button1 = new Button(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        holder.phoneContainer..addView(button1, params);
```