# Trying to match this design in recycler view item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The task is to make chat dialog to be like this image how can i make the background of every item to match this design i'm thinking about using card view but how can i add the extra slice for every item please help.

[image]

Update:

Here's the image for anyone in need:

[image]

Comment: It's just a recyclerview with different items.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914003/recyclerview-and-handling-different-type-of-row-inflation

Comment: Thanks man but i mean the item itself how can i make the background itself to match this design i'm thinking about using card view but how can i make the extra slice on the right side and left side

Comment: Png image with padding (Imageview) inside a layout

Comment: Is it going to expand if the text is large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide special images with extension .9.png. It calls 9-Patch files.

[Here is more info about them.](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html)

In short, you need to create a simple png file with message background and in border of image mark extensible parts of image by black lines. Thus you will have opportunity to resize your image, but don't affect to it corners, for example, or some parts, that you don't want to resize.

Hope this helps.

Here is image to show, what can be achieved:
[image]

[image]

Comment: @Muhammad Keep me informed

Comment: @Muhammad Did you figure out how to use it? Have you succeeded?

Comment: I'm still missing the design from the designer once i get it i'll tell you how it went.