# Different types of rows in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder, linearlayoutmanager

I receive data (an object with few elements inside) from a server and I want to show it in RecyclerView. Each object could contain 2, 3, 4.. or even 18 elements (as on the picture):
[image]

I know how to create different types of rows from pre-created XML layouts and use all these in RecyclerView, but how to deal with object with 
for example 18 elements?

Should I generate rows based on a number of elements in each object and after that inflate it in the adapter?

So, how to deal with 20+ different types of rows in 1 RecyclerView?

Comment: already answer is provided just see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914003/recyclerview-and-handling-different-type-of-row-inflation)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type

Comment: your link useful for 2 or maybe 3 types of rows. My question is how to deal with 20+ different types of rows in 1 recyclerview?

Comment: Try using expandablegridview