# How to add multiple viewType in cursoradapter recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have researched lot before posting this question am using cursorrecyclerviewadapter in that how can i use multiple view type i could not find any sample on this now let me explain my problem i need to add header to my recyclerview items like alphabetical header how can i achieve this with cursor recyclerview adapter here let me post my code:

```
public class CustomerListAdapter extends CursorRecycleViewAdapter<CustomerListAdapter.MyViewHolder>  implements View.OnClickListener , RecyclerViewFastScroller.BubbleTextGetter{
    int position;
    Cursor cursor;
    ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    List<CustomerModel>list;



    public CustomerListAdapter(Context mContext, Cursor cursor) {
        super(mContext, cursor);

    }


    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTextToShowInBubble(int pos) {
        return Character.toString(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerModel.Customer_Name)).charAt(0));
    }


    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textname;
        TextView status;
        TextView textphnum;
        TextView textdegree;
        TextView textemail;
        ImageView call;

        public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.textname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subject);
            this.status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.customerstatus);
            this.textemail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            this.textdegree=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
            this.call = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.customeradapterview, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        return myViewHolder;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView textViewName = holder.textname;
        TextView textstatus = holder.status;
        TextView textphnumbr = holder.textphnum;
        TextView textemail=holder.textemail;
        String  companygrp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerModel.Customer_Name));
        String email=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerModel.Customer_EmailID));
        if(email.length()>=20){
            String s=  email.substring(0,20)+"...";
            textemail.setText(s);
        }
        else {
            textemail.setText(email);
        }
        //textemail.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerModel.Customer_EmailID)));
        String status=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerModel.Customer_Status));
        if(status.equals("Active")){
            textstatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#006400"));
        }
        else {
            textstatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8B0000"));
        }
        textstatus.setText(status);
        textphnumbr.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerModel.Customer_MobileNumber)));
        String s1 = companygrp.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + companygrp.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        textViewName.setText(s1);
        ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.DEFAULT;
        String com= s1.substring(0,1);
        TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
                .buildRound((com).toUpperCase(), generator.getRandomColor());
        holder.call.setImageDrawable(drawable);

     /*  for (int i = 0; i < companygrp.length(); i++) {
            String s1 = companygrp.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + companygrp.substring(1).toLowerCase();
            textViewName.setText(s1);
            ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.DEFAULT;
            String com= s1.substring(0,1);
            TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
                    .buildRound((com).toUpperCase(), generator.getRandomColor());
            holder.call.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.getParent();
        position = recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(v);
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            final Cursor cursor = this.getItem(position);
            this.onItemClickListener.onItemClicked(cursor);
        }

    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClicked(Cursor cursor);
    }

}
```

How to add header to my recyclerview am struck in this can anyone tell me the solution for this Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recyclerview and handling different type of row inflation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914003/recyclerview-and-handling-different-type-of-row-inflation)

Comment: Have you read my question completely before marking it as duplicate please read it fully@AskhayBhat

Comment: There is no difference in using multiple view types if you are using recyclerViewAdapter or cursorAdapter.

Comment: What do you mean by 'alphabetical headers'? Add a screenshot of what you want.

Comment: do i need inherit  RecyclerView.Adapter in my case i have to extend cursorrecyclerviewadapter class@AkshayBhat

Comment: Headers like recyclers item first letter @Abbas

Comment: Whatever you extend doesn't matter, you have to modify the condition in `getItemViewType()` and use that view type in `onBindViewHolder()` and `onCreateViewHolder()`.

Comment: see `android.widget.AlphabetIndexer`