# RecyclerView item with collection of images

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview, image-gallery

I'm tring to make some like RecyclerView  list item image grid. It's has one main big image and some with other sizes. I've idea to use some like other holders for each image count, and choose it in adapter onCreateViewHolder method. But, I think, isn't good idea. Maybe you know some libraries or know some good practice examples?

[image: image gallety container]

Comment: Use a Image Library like Picasso or something similiar.

Comment: picasso it's for image load. But I need layout with dinamic change of images views

Comment: No need to use a library simply use glide or picasso for image caching. And create ViewHolder for each type of item. and change itemType on basis of your layout. and you are good to go.

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914003/recyclerview-and-handling-different-type-of-row-inflation may help

Comment: follow this link https://github.com/yuvaraj119/Picasso-RecyclerView-StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Comment: Also this one would work for you http://android-er.blogspot.com.tr/2015/11/gallery-like-recyclerview-cardview.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `GridLayoutManager` and a custom `SpanSizeLookup`.

`GridLayoutManager` gives you the capability of saying how many columns (rows) you want a certain item to span by creating a `SpanSizeLookup`.  The code looks like this:

```
    // Create a grid layout with four columns
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 4);

    // Create a custom SpanSizeLookup where the first item spans all four columns
    layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            return position == 0 ? 4 : 1;
        }
    });
```