# How implement multi view types for RecycleView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Currently, I work on custom multi-view types for RecycleView.
I found many solutions for this problem, but I will share my way.

The different is use `enum` for define ViewType.

See my answer for more detail.
(Just want to share).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recyclerview and handling different type of row inflation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914003/recyclerview-and-handling-different-type-of-row-inflation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I recommend read this article: [Writing Better Adapter](https://proandroiddev.com/writing-better-adapters-1b09758407d2)

---

Here is the way I custom multi-view types for RecyclewView.

I will show the code first, then explain bellow.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class BaseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private final List<Wrapper<?>> items;

    public BaseAdapter() {
        this.items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return items.get(position).viewType;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return ViewType.values()[viewType].onCreateViewHolder(parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.onBind(items.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }


    public void simulateAddItems() {
        items.add(new Wrapper<>(ViewType.USER.viewTYpe(), new User()));
        items.add(new Wrapper<>(ViewType.USER.viewTYpe(), new User()));
        items.add(new Wrapper<>(ViewType.USER.viewTYpe(), new User()));
        items.add(new Wrapper<>(ViewType.BOTTOM.viewTYpe(), new BottomData()));

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public enum ViewType {
        USER {
            @Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
                return new UserViewHolder(itemView);
            }
        },
        BOTTOM {
            @Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
                return new BottomViewHolder(itemView);
            }
        };

        public abstract ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent);

        public int viewTYpe() {
            return ordinal();
        }
    }


    static class Wrapper<T> {
        final int viewType;
        final T data;

        public Wrapper(int viewType, T data) {
            this.viewType = viewType;
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolder<T> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private T item;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }


        public void onBind(T item) {
        }
    }

    public static class UserViewHolder extends ViewHolder<User> {

        public UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBind(User item) {
            super.onBind(item);
        }
    }

    public static class BottomViewHolder extends ViewHolder<BottomData> {

        public BottomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBind(BottomData item) {
            super.onBind(item);
        }
    }


    static class User {
        // user fields & method
    }

    static class BottomData {
        // bottom data fields & method
    }
}
```

You can see the adapter have something special:

1. The data of Adapter is generic & extends from `Wrapper` class. The `Wrapper` class simply POJO class contain two fields `viewType` & `item` data. The `viewType` will be passing via `getItemViewType(int position)` and the `item` is data for each view holder.
2. The generic `ViewHolder` with `T` is kind of data for the view holder. You can see two custom view holder `UserViewHolder` and `BottomViewHolder` extends from `ViewHolder` with this data. (So in `onBind` of each view holder will have exact data they want to use -> no need to cast. Because we already in cast).
3. The enum `ViewType` contain all view type of adapter. Also, in view type, we have method `ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent)` so we can easier make viewHolder from `ViewType`. I think it is easier for our eyes to see the Holder relative to the ViewType.

Also, we have method `viewType()` it simply return `ordinal()` of enum.
As a reference in `java docs` that method may not use. But in this case, I think it is fair enough to use (because it is unique).

So in the method `onCreateViewHolder` of Adapter we can simple call:
`return ViewType.values()[viewType].onCreateViewHolder(parent);`

and in `onBindViewHolder` we will call `holder.onBind(items.get(position));`.

Finally, I made `simulateAddItems` for demo how we add item to the adapter.

Here is some experiences while working with custom view type for RecycleView. I hope it useful & help other people.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that adding any methods to enums inhibits Proguard enum optimizations. With these optimizations, it's as if you set constant ints in your code. There's a non-zero performance penalty to enums which are too smart on Android.