# ERROR : int android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.mItemViewType

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I Have error : int android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.mItemViewType

I checked in this part have error  Help me to solve this error...Friends I am creating chatapp so I am including two layouts in my chat this is my code

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v;
        switch (viewType) {
            case TYPE_SENT:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_message_sent, parent, false);
                return new sendmsgviewholder(v);

            case TYPE_RECEIVED:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_message_received, parent, false);
                return new receivedviewholder(v);
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Messages c = mMessageList.get(position);

        String from_user=c.getFrom();
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case TYPE_SENT:
                ((sendmsgviewholder)holder).messageText.setText(c.getMessage());
                break;

            case TYPE_RECEIVED:
                ((receivedviewholder)holder).messageText.setText(c.getMessage());
                break;
        }


    }
```

Comment: `@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return int
    }
  `
 the problem might be here, if you return different value from TYPE_SENT, TYPE_RECEIVED

Comment: @Harish Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type) solution

Comment: write implementation logic of viewtype in getItemViewType. your getItemViewType returns just position.

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914003/recyclerview-and-handling-different-type-of-row-inflation

Comment: Friends complete my code

Comment: This is chat app friends complete my code

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
   private int TYPE_SENT= 1;
   private int TYPE_RECEIVED= 2;

 @Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    switch (viewType) {
        case TYPE_SENT:
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_message_sent, parent, null);
            return new sendmsgviewholder(v);

        case TYPE_RECEIVED:
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_message_received, parent, null);
            return new receivedviewholder(v);
    }
    return viewHolder;
}
```

Comment: Thank u @mehul, Sơn Phạm, Harshad Prajapati, ArbenMaloku, Bek

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you did override method

> getItemViewType(int position)

which returns one of those value TYPE_SENT, TYPE_RECEIVED

and also i see u return a RecyclerView.ViewHolder. You should create your own ViewHolder by extending Recyclerview.ViewHolder. Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)