# I want the text in the middle of cardview if there is no image in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, cardview

I have a `RecyclerView` with a `Cardview`. I got it to work if there is no image in the `ArrayList`, but it still puts the text at the bottom.

Like this:

[image: This is how it looks now:]

I am wondering if its possible (and if - how please) to get the text of this `CardView` in the middle if there is no image. Maybe with `Java` or in the `XML` file.

Here is my `XML` file:

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/image"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/more_text5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_name"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the adapter:

```
     public class SnapRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SnapRecyclerAdapter.ReyclerViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Item> items;

public SnapRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public ReyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View item = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_view, parent, false);

    return new ReyclerViewHolder(item);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ReyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = items.get(position);
    if(holder.image == null){
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
    else {
    holder.image.setImageResource(item.getDrawable());
    holder.appName.setText(item.getName());
    holder.moreInfo.setText(item.getMore_info());}}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

class ReyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView image;
    private TextView appName;
    private TextView moreInfo;

    private ReyclerViewHolder(final View v) {
        super(v);
        image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        appName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
        moreInfo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.more_text5);
    }
}
}
```

Needless to say that as always help (and patience with our new guys lol) is really appreciated.

Comment: just check condition...if image is null then set imageview visibility to GONE.

Comment: holder.appName.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); holder.moreInfo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ReyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = items.get(position);
    if(holder.image == null){
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
    else {
    holder.image.setImageResource(item.getDrawable());
    holder.appName.setText(item.getName());
    holder.moreInfo.setText(item.getMore_info());
    holder.appName.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    holder.moreInfo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); 

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

first things first, thanks for the responses, but none of them seems to work. From what I found is, you have to create a RecyclerView with two viewTypes.

See the questions here:
[How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

And also here:
[Recyclerview and handling different type of row inflation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914003/recyclerview-and-handling-different-type-of-row-inflation/29362643#29362643)

But what I did in the end is to make an Image with the text on. I know its a shortcut, and I might run into some other trouble in the long run, but for the time its working, and I just realized today that there can be more than one way of doing a thing. Yes maybe not the best way, but its working.

The biggest reason why I like it is because I find it much easier to handle the multiple lines of text on a image, than in XML or in the Arraylist with \n.