# put ads inside recyclerview for every 5 item?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, android-recyclerview

I have problem with recyclerview, i want to put ads in my recyclerview (not native ads from google). ads is come from API. i want to put that ads in my recyclerview that have news that come from API.

So, i have 2 response from api at once to put into recyclerview. Here are my news response and ads response.

news response api
https://jsonblob.com/7ba93af8-6884-11e8-94d5-4b6d8b2939b5

ads response api
https://jsonblob.com/5010a591-6884-11e8-94d5-6505b8737ba5.

I want to show my ads in every 5 news, what is the best way i can do for put ads between my recyclerview?

[EDI 1]
this my adapter

```
package com.asosiasidosenindonesia.adi.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.asosiasidosenindonesia.adi.model.response.AdsResponse;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.asosiasidosenindonesia.adi.R;
import com.asosiasidosenindonesia.adi.activity.DetailNewsActivity;
import com.asosiasidosenindonesia.adi.config.Constant;
import com.asosiasidosenindonesia.adi.model.response.NewsResponse;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

/**
 * Created by Personal on 13/04/18.
 */

public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    public final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    /*
    *
    * VIEW TYPE FOR ITEM RECYCLREVIEW
    * There is two common item type :
    * 1) CONTENT_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = FOR ITEM IN RECYCLERVIEW
    * 2) ADS_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = FOR ADS TO SHOW IN RECYCLERVIEW
    */
    private static final int CONTENT_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = 0;
    private static final int ADS_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = 1;

    private static final int ADS_LIST_DALTA = 4;

    Context context;

    public int i = 0;

    //Collection of data
    List<NewsResponse.Data> datas = new ArrayList<>();
    List<AdsResponse.Data> adsDatas = new ArrayList<>();

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, List<NewsResponse.Data> datas, List<AdsResponse.Data> adsDatas) {
        this.context = context;
        this.datas = datas;
        this.adsDatas = adsDatas;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        //For Content News
        View content = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_item_news,parent,false);

        //For Ads
        View ads = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.ads_320_150,parent,false);

        switch (viewType){
            case CONTENT_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
                NewsHolder newsHolder = new NewsHolder(content);
                return newsHolder;
            case ADS_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
                AdsHolder adsHolder = new AdsHolder(ads);
                return adsHolder;
            default:
                AdsHolder newsHolder1 = new AdsHolder(ads);
                return newsHolder1;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (holder instanceof NewsHolder){
            ((NewsHolder) holder).populateNewsHolder(datas.get(getRealPosition(position)));
        }else if (holder instanceof AdsHolder){
            if (i < 5){
                ((AdsHolder) holder).populateAds(adsDatas.get(i));
            }
            i++;
        }

    }

    private int getRealPosition(int position){
        if (ADS_LIST_DALTA == 0){
            return position;
        }else{
            return position - position/ADS_LIST_DALTA;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        int additionalContent = 0;
        if (datas.size() > 0 && ADS_LIST_DALTA > 0 && datas.size() > ADS_LIST_DALTA){
            additionalContent = datas.size() / ADS_LIST_DALTA;
        }

        return  datas.size() + additionalContent;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        if (position > 0 && position % ADS_LIST_DALTA == 0){
            return ADS_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
        }

        return CONTENT_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;

    }

    /*View Holder Type For News*/
    public class NewsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.tv_slug)
        TextView tvSlug;
        @BindView(R.id.tv_title)
        TextView tvTitle;
        @BindView(R.id.tv_kategori)
        TextView tvKategori;
        @BindView(R.id.tv_tgl_event)
        TextView tvTglNews;
        @BindView(R.id.iv_news)
        ImageView ivNews;

        public NewsHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Toast.makeText(context, tvTitle.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent toDetail = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), DetailNewsActivity.class);
                    toDetail.putExtra(Constant.SLUG, tvSlug.getText().toString());
                    itemView.getContext().startActivity(toDetail);
                }
            });
        }

        public void populateNewsHolder(NewsResponse.Data model){

            tvSlug.setText(model.getSlug());
            tvTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
            tvTglNews.setText(model.getCreatedAt().getDateFriendly()+", "+model.getCreatedAt().getDate());
            tvKategori.setText("#"+model.getKategori().getNama());

            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(model.getFoto())
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.banner)
                    .error(R.drawable.banner)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .skipMemoryCache(true)
                    .into(ivNews);
        }
    }

    /*View Holder Type For Ads*/
    public class AdsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        @BindView(R.id.iv_ads)
        ImageView ivAds;
        @BindView(R.id.tv_name)
        TextView tvName;

        public AdsHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, tvName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

        }

        public void populateAds(AdsResponse.Data data){
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(data.getAdsImage())
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .into(ivAds);
            tvName.setText(data.getImageName());
        }
    }

    public void resetAdsPosition(){
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

This is my fragment to fetch data

```
package com.asosiasidosenindonesia.adi.fragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.asosiasidosenindonesia.adi.activity.DetailNewsActivity;
import com.asosiasidosenindonesia.adi.config.Constant;
import com.asosiasidosenindonesia.adi.model.response.AdsResponse;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderTypes.BaseSliderView;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderTypes.TextSliderView;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.asosiasidosenindonesia.adi.R;
import com.asosiasidosenindonesia.adi.adapter.EventAdapter;
import com.asosiasidosenindonesia.adi.adapter.NewsAdapter;
import com.asosiasidosenindonesia.adi.config.PrefHandler;
import com.asosiasidosenindonesia.adi.model.response.EventResponse;
import com.asosiasidosenindonesia.adi.model.response.HeadlineResponse;
import com.asosiasidosenindonesia.adi.model.response.NewsResponse;
import com.asosiasidosenindonesia.adi.network.NetworkClient;
import com.asosiasidosenindonesia.adi.network.ServiceGeneratorAuth;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import dmax.dialog.SpotsDialog;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {


    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    private SpotsDialog spotDialogs;

    private int page = 1, adsSize = 5;
    private boolean itShouldLoadMore = true;

    Context context;
    EventAdapter adapter;
    NewsAdapter adapterNews;

    List<NewsResponse.Data> datasNews = new ArrayList<>();
    List<HeadlineResponse.Data> datasHeadlines = new ArrayList<>();
    List<AdsResponse.Data> dataAds = new ArrayList<>();

    @BindView(R.id.nested_scroll_view)
    NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;
    @BindView(R.id.rv_news)
    RecyclerView rvNews;
    @BindView(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout)
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    @BindView(R.id.image_slider)
    SliderLayout imageSlider;
    @BindView(R.id.cv_empty)
    CardView cvEmpty;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_message)
    TextView tvMessage;

    public NewsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = getContext();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);

        init(view);

        getNewsHeadlines();

        getNews();

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                datasNews.clear();
                adapterNews.notifyDataSetChanged();
                page = 1;
                itShouldLoadMore = true;
                getNews();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

    /*First inisialize*/
    private void init(View view) {
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        PrefHandler.init(getActivity());
        spotDialogs = new SpotsDialog(getActivity());

        //News
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        rvNews.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        rvNews.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        rvNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapterNews = new NewsAdapter(context,datasNews, dataAds);
        rvNews.setAdapter(adapterNews);

        rvNews.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);


        nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                if(v.getChildAt(v.getChildCount() - 1) != null) {
                    if ((scrollY >= (v.getChildAt(v.getChildCount() - 1).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight())) &&
                            scrollY > oldScrollY) {
                        if (itShouldLoadMore == true){
                            getNewsMore();
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Memuat event yang diikuti lainnya..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
//                            Toast.makeText(context, "Sudah tidak ada data yang dimuat..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void getAds() {
        dataAds.clear();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 5){
            AdsResponse.Data data = new AdsResponse.Data(R.drawable.ads_320_150, "Iklan "+i, "https://anggit.me");
            dataAds.add(data);
            i++;
        }
    }

    /*Get News Headlines*/
    private void getNewsHeadlines(){
        datasHeadlines.clear();
        Call<HeadlineResponse> call = ServiceGeneratorAuth.createService(NetworkClient.class, PrefHandler.getTokenKey(), getActivity())
                .getNewsHeadlines("desc", "", "headline");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<HeadlineResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<HeadlineResponse> call, Response<HeadlineResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){

                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(response.body()));

                    int i = 0;
                    while (i < response.body().getData().size() && i <= 5){

                        HeadlineResponse.Data data = new HeadlineResponse.Data(response.body().getData().get(i).getUpdatedAt(),response.body().getData().get(i).getCreatedAt(),
                                response.body().getData().get(i).getKategori(),response.body().getData().get(i).getProvinsi(),response.body().getData().get(i).getUser(),
                                response.body().getData().get(i).getHeadline(),response.body().getData().get(i).getPageViews(),response.body().getData().get(i).getDeskripsi(),
                                response.body().getData().get(i).getFoto(),response.body().getData().get(i).getSlug(),response.body().getData().get(i).getTitle());

                        datasHeadlines.add(data);

                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString(Constant.ID_EVENT, response.body().getData().get(i).getSlug());

                        TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(context);
                        textSliderView.description(response.body().getData().get(i).getTitle())
                                .bundle(bundle)
                                .image(response.body().getData().get(i).getFoto())
                                .empty(R.drawable.banner)
                                .setOnSliderClickListener(new BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {
                                        Intent toDetail = new Intent(context, DetailNewsActivity.class);
                                        toDetail.putExtra(Constant.SLUG, slider.getBundle().getString(Constant.ID_EVENT));
                                        getActivity().startActivity(toDetail);
                                    }
                                });

                        imageSlider.setDuration(500000);

                        imageSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);

                        i++;
                    }


                    //Cek apakah headline ada
                    if (datasHeadlines.size() == 0){
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Gak ada");
                        TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(context);
                        textSliderView.description("")
                                .image(R.drawable.banner)
                                .empty(R.drawable.banner);

                        imageSlider.setDuration(500000);

                        imageSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
                    }else{
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Ada");
                    }

                }else{
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Gagal");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<HeadlineResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    /*Get News First Page*/
    private void getNews(){
        spotDialogs.show();
        datasNews.clear();
        Call<NewsResponse> call = ServiceGeneratorAuth.createService(NetworkClient.class, PrefHandler.getTokenKey(), getActivity())
                .getNews("desc");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<NewsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<NewsResponse> call, Response<NewsResponse> response) {
                spotDialogs.dismiss();
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(response.body()));

                    int i = 0;
                    while (i < response.body().getData().size()){

                        NewsResponse.Data data = new NewsResponse.Data(response.body().getData().get(i).getUpdatedAt(),response.body().getData().get(i).getCreatedAt(),
                                response.body().getData().get(i).getKategori(),response.body().getData().get(i).getProvinsi(),response.body().getData().get(i).getUser(),
                                response.body().getData().get(i).getHeadline(),response.body().getData().get(i).getCountViewer(),response.body().getData().get(i).getDeskripsi(),
                                response.body().getData().get(i).getFoto(),response.body().getData().get(i).getSlug(),response.body().getData().get(i).getTitle());
                        datasNews.add(data);
                        i++;
                    }

                    getAds();

                    adapterNews.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    page = response.body().getMeta().getCurrentPage()+1;

                    if (page >= response.body().getMeta().getLastPage()){
                        itShouldLoadMore = false;
                    }else{
                        itShouldLoadMore = true;
                    }

                    if (adapterNews.getItemCount() == 0){
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Kosong");
                        showEmpty();
                        tvMessage.setText("Belum ada berita hari ini..");
                    }else{
                        hideEmpty();
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Gagal");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<NewsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                spotDialogs.dismiss();
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    /*Get Event More Based On Page*/
    private void getNewsMore(){
        Call<NewsResponse> call = ServiceGeneratorAuth.createService(NetworkClient.class, PrefHandler.getTokenKey(), context)
                .getNewsMore(String.valueOf(page), "desc");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<NewsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<NewsResponse> call, Response<NewsResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(response.body()));

                    int i = 0;
                    while (i < response.body().getData().size()){
                        NewsResponse.Data data = new NewsResponse.Data(response.body().getData().get(i).getUpdatedAt(),response.body().getData().get(i).getCreatedAt(),
                                response.body().getData().get(i).getKategori(),response.body().getData().get(i).getProvinsi(),response.body().getData().get(i).getUser(),
                                response.body().getData().get(i).getHeadline(),response.body().getData().get(i).getCountViewer(),response.body().getData().get(i).getDeskripsi(),
                                response.body().getData().get(i).getFoto(),response.body().getData().get(i).getSlug(),response.body().getData().get(i).getTitle());
                        datasNews.add(data);
                        i++;
                    }

                    adapterNews.resetAdsPosition();

                    getAds();

                    adapterNews.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    page = response.body().getMeta().getCurrentPage()+1;

                    if (page >= response.body().getMeta().getLastPage()){
                        itShouldLoadMore = false;
                    }else{
                        itShouldLoadMore = true;
                    }

                }else{
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Gagal");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<NewsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        imageSlider.stopAutoCycle();
        super.onStop();
    }

    /*Update UI*/
    private void showEmpty(){
        cvEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rvNews.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void hideEmpty(){
        cvEmpty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rvNews.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to put ads in my recyclerview

`getItemViewType(int position)` this is what you have to use to show multiple items in the same recyclerview

> put ads inside recyclerview for every 5 item?

Before populating the data to the adapter you need to merge the data from both api arrange it in the format you need and do it, you have to use different ItemViewType of the recyclerview to achieve this.

As an example you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914003/recyclerview-and-handling-different-type-of-row-inflation)

Comment: thanks for anwering, so i cant just throw that 2 list to adapter to put ads inside recyevlview for every 5 items?

Comment: yes but the arrangement has to be done before you populate the adapter, also check that example out it will be useful

Comment: if you are using rxjava then you can if not do it separately